# Jquery- How to remove a link (<a href> tag) for a certain dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdwon selection and a div that reacts to the change of selection of the dropdown values. Basically I have two things:
1) On domready I have a default value 'All' selected. When the 'All' text is selected, i need to remove a link from the div: here is the code for the dropdown:

```
 <select name="selectedRegion" id="selectedRegion">
  <option>All</option>
  <option>SF</option>
  <option>NY</option>
 <select>
```

I cannot use `.val()` to get the selected value as the value for 'All' is dynamically generated and will be different for different values.

below is the div that has link to be removed when the dropdown selection is 'All':

```
<div class="test-info" id = "test-info"><h3 class="info-title">Title</h3>
 <div class="region-table" id ="region-table">
 <dl>
  <dt class="label">Transactions:</dt>
    <dd class="value"><span class="stats-transactions link">23</span></dd> 
  <dt class="label">Failures:</dt>
   <dd class="value"><span class="stats-failures link">22</span></dd>
 </dl>
</div></div>
```

The `class="link"` suggests the link that i want to remove on page load.
Basically for all the other options, other than the default 'All', I would have the link assigned. 
I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$('.stats-transactions ').removeClass('link')})
```

and it removed link for the 'Transactions'. I can add a class to all the 'spans' to rmeove link on page load.
How do i get the link back `onchange`, selecting other option to show up the link and selecting the option back to 'All' should remove the link?

How can i do this?. Help really appreciated.

Comment: trying to understand... you just want to remove all of the "link" classes onload and then add them back one at a time for each of your options or else when "All" is selected, remove the "link" classes again?

Comment: The question is a bit confusing on what you want to have happen here.  If 'All' is selected, remove the class link? And then put it back if it's not 'All' that's selected?

Comment: instead of removing it, take a new class, called `removed`. on selection, remove all remove all `removed` classes, then add `removed` to the link you want removed.

Comment: Your question doesn't match your title very well. Are you trying to remove a class or an element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I'd do two things. First, don't put `.link` on the element initially. Then, use the `selectedIndex` of the select as a test:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/8Wv9R/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#selectedRegion').change(function () {
        if ( this.selectedIndex != 0 ) {
            $('.stats-transactions ').addClass('link');
        } else {
            $('.stats-transactions ').removeClass('link')
        }
    });
});
```

If for some reason you can't modify the HTML, simply run your original statement on load, and then the change function:

```
$('.stats-transactions ').removeClass('link')

$('#selectedRegion').change(function () {
...
```